# Java security error Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_OPERATION_ACTIVE

Tags: java, security, gridfs

We are seeing java security error randomly on our java job.
This error comes randomly when we pick xml files from windows server and parse them on Linux server trying to save in MongoGridFS. 
The problem is when we restart this job it start working fine again for same data.

```
update() failed
java.security.ProviderException: update() failed
                                    at 
sun.security.pkcs11.P11Digest.engineUpdate(P11Digest.java:228)
                                    at java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate.engineUpdate(MessageDigest.java:568)
                                    at java.security.MessageDigest.update(MessageDigest.java:323)
                                    at com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSInputFile.dumpBuffer(GridFSInputFile.java:280)
                                    at com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSInputFile.saveChunks(GridFSInputFile.java:229)
                                    at com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSInputFile.save(GridFSInputFile.java:178)
                                    at com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSInputFile.save(GridFSInputFile.java:160)

                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_OPERATION_ACTIVE
                                    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_DigestInit(Native Method)
                                    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Digest.engineUpdate(P11Digest.java:210)
                                    ... 16 more
```

java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.3.3.el6-x86_64 u45-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID:    CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Could you please help me with this issue as it has become critical.

Thanks 
Virendra Agarwal